# Vista-Eclipse (Galileo) CDT w/ MinGW and MinGW's GDB fails to output cerr output

Tags: c++, g++, eclipse-cdt, vista64, eclipse-3.5

I installed Eclipse and I can get g++ to compile the code correctly; however, when I start the debugger none of the "cerr >>" outputs are ever displayed in the Eclipse console. I tried to run GDB manually and it, too, does not display the cerr output. Is anyone else experiencing this?? I am running the GDB 5.3-something that is available with MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

I think newer versions of GDB work on Windows Vista.  Version 6.8 or something is available with the [TDM-GCC](http://www.tdragon.net/recentgcc/) project.

Comment: I tried 6.8, 7.02, and 7.10; 6.8 still had the problem. 7+ does not seem to have the problem on the command line, using -mi; however, Eclipse CDT does not print any of the CERR messages that are output by gdb.